# Workspace BigQuery - Finding inactive accounts

Tags: google-workspace

I'm super new to using BigQuery, and only in the context of supporting Google Workspace. I have our tenant configured to export to BigQuery in an effort to analyze information more effectively.

The first problem I'm looking to solve is identifying Inactive Email Accounts. My company uses a lot of mailboxes as Shared Accounts via Delegation, set up in support of specific events. Unfortunately, we aren't informed when they are done being used for those events, and will sit idle and eat up a license.

After having limited success using GAdmin's internal report, I pushed the data to BigQuery. At first, I tried using the gmail.num_emails_received and gmail.num_emails_sent data, but that only returns and integer and doesn't seem to be able to be filtered by a date range.

Similarly, I tried gmail.last_interaction however that data only seems to go back 3 months, which isn't enough to properly determine inactivity for our purposes.

Is there a better way to determine this? Thank you all so much in advance.